# cakephp3- unable to post form data to controller function

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a contact us form and user enter data and submits it. This data needs to accessed in controller function so I can send a mail to admin informing about the user request recently received.

But when I press submit button, nothing happens. Form just reloads and the contactus form (view page) is shown to the users. I don't know why the data is not getting passed to the controller function.

I'mm new to CakePHP framework and I'm using CakePHP3 for development purposes.

Here is my form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'contactus']]); ?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('fname', ['placeholder' => 'Your name.' , 'id' => 'fname', 'required' => 'required']); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('mail', ['placeholder' => 'Your email.' , 'id' => 'mail', 'required' => 'required']); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('subject', ['placeholder' => 'Write something.', 'id' => 'subject']); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <?php echo $this->Form->button(__('Submit')); ?>
    </div>         
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

And my controller function is:

```
 public function contactus()
 {
        $pages ='';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) 
        {
            $pages =   $this->request->data('Contact');
        }
        $this->set(compact('pages'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['pages']);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me the mistakes I made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your form is submitting but not through the post method. So I would like to say you that, please make the bellow changes before submitting the form.

```
$pages ='';
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
        echo "Request is post";die;
        $pages =   $this->request->data('Contact');
    }else{
        echo "request is not post";die;
    }
    $this->set(compact('pages'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['pages']);
```

Now check, which is printing in the display. Then I can help you further.

> Remember: - fill the form, then after change the controller method, then press submit method.

Comment: I tried, nothing gets printed. I fill the form, then I click submit button but I don't see the echo as per the solution. It seems like the form reloads and nothing else. I just see the contact us form again. @bikash.bilz

Comment: Maybe there is wrong method calling while form submit. Use cake form helper, I think this will help you. You can take follow up from this link. @Anna Belle
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html

Comment: Or at least in the start of the form use
<?= $this->Form->create(null,array('url' => ['controller' => 'Logins', 'action' => 'login'],'id'=>'contact-form','class'=>'form-signin','inputDefaults'=>array(
                                'label'=>false
                            ))); ?>

And in the form closing use <?= $this->Form->end() ?>

Don't write html form tags, as it will create automatically by cake. Hope this will help surely.

@Anna Belle

Comment: I used form helper to build form now but its still doing nothing. @bikash.bilz

Comment: Last thing I can guess is use "<?= $this->Form->submit('Click me')?>;" instead of button type submit. If this not works then, Need to debug, if you feel comfortable share your TV. @Anna Belle

Comment: Let me try this code. If it doesnot work, i will share my code @bikash.bilz

Comment: Okay @AnnaBelle

Comment: In your controller's functions 1st line add this, let me know the response var_dump($this->request->is([POST, PATCH, PUT])); die;